# Anotação para criar Index Unique que aceite null com EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework-6

Quero criar o seguinte Index em uma tabela por anotação:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_yourcolumn_notnull
ON YourTable(yourcolumn)
WHERE yourcolumn IS NOT NULL;
```

[Origem do SQL acima](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767702).

O maximo que conseguir fazer foi criar um index unique, mas ele não aceita dois nulls.

Isso seria possível com EF6 e SQLServer 2012?

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo, infelizmente não acho que seja possivel, porém através do Migrations é possivel criar uma solução de contorno.

após usar os comandos `-EnableMigration` e `add-migration %Migration Name%`, abra o arquivo de migração recem criado e edicione a seguinte linha dentro do método `Up`:

```
Sql(string.Format(@"CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IXCU_{0}_{1}_notnull
ON {0}({1}) WHERE yourcolumn IS NOT NULL", nomeTabela, nomeColuna);
```

caso já exista um indice com o mesmo nome do banco de dados, não esqueça de adicionar a seguinte linha no método `Down`:

```
DropIndex(nomeTabela, string.Format("IXCU_{0}_{1}_notnull", nomeTabela, nomeColuna));
```

Agora você pode executar o `update-database`.

Comment: Essa era meu plano B, eu tinha visto alguma coisa assim [nesse post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24365764/3517631). Vou fazer alguns teste aqui.